# Userlogs is empty

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a simple mapreduce program with one job, but the job is failing. I want to check the logs, but my userlogs folder in the /hadoop/logs folder is empty. When using the http://localhost:50070/logs/userlogs/ UI, I find that the userlogs folder is modified whenever I run my program, but it still remains empty! Why is this happening? I can't do any debugging whatsoever because nothing shows up in the console either.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're pointing to the wrong logs.  50070 is the port for the Hadoop 2 NameNode.  Typically MapReduce runs against YARN or MRv1.  So you would need to look at their logs to diagnose your problem.